# Ajax подгрузка сообщений

Tags: ajax

Вообще написал я такой вот простой код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#imgLoad").hide();

    var inputMessage = $("#message");
    var messageList = $(".dialogs");
    var num = 1;

    function updateShoutbox(){

        function reload(){

            $("#load div").click(function(){
            $("#imgLoad").show();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/app/ajax/update.php",
                data: { id: <?php echo $dg['id'] ?>, coll: num },
                complete: function(data){
                    if(data == 0){
                        alert("Больше нет записей");
                        $("#imgLoad").hide();
                    } else {
                        $(messageList.html(data.responseText)).append(data);
                        num = num + 5;
                        $("#imgLoad").hide();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        }
        setInterval(reload, 3000);
    }

    function checkForm(){
        if( inputMessage.attr("value"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    updateShoutbox();

    $("#form").submit(function(){

        if(checkForm()){
            var message = inputMessage.attr("value");

            $("#message").val("");
            $("#send").attr({ disabled:true, value:"Отправляю..." });
            $("#send").blur();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/app/ajax/send.php",
                data: { userid: <?php echo $users['id'] ?>,
                        dgid: <?php echo $dg['id'] ?>,
                        message: message
                      },
                complete: function(data){
                    $("#send").attr({ disabled:false, value:"Отправить" });
                }
             });
        }
        else alert("Пожалуйста, напишите сообщение");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Тут возникло пару проблем, при переходе в диалог сообщения не отображаются, пока не нажата кнопка, второй момент как сделать новые сообщения внизу. третий момент при нажатии на кнопку не появляются старые сообщения сверху.

Где косяки, и как исправить?

Comment: Апну топик

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идея проста. На document вешается событие `scroll`, в котором проверяется, а не находимся ли мы на самом верху страницы (`if($(this).scrollTop() < 20`). Если это так, шлем AJAX с запросом ранних сообщений

Comment: @dan_aka_skiff, вы забыли добавить: "*Ваш К.О.*" ))

Comment: Ok да. я уже глянул в другую сторону, сейчас изменю вопрос